# Python: Find the position in a list of the first object that respect a given condition

Tags: python, search

I have a list of the following kind:

```
class Any(object):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b

l=[Any(1,3),Any(2,4),Any(1,2),Any(None,6),Any('hello',6), Any(1,'ChuckNorris'),Any(1,2)]
```

`l`is a list that contains only instances of `Any`. I'd like to find the position of the first of these instances which attribute `a` equals 'None`.

As my list is very long, the algorithm should not explore the whole list but it should stop as soon as the condition (in my example, attribute `a` equals `None`) is found.

In the above example the answer of this algorithm should be 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a generator expression and [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
next((i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item.a is None), None)
```

This would return `None` if no such item is found.

**Demo:**

```
>>> l=[Any(1,3),Any(2,4),Any(1,2),Any(None,6),Any('hello',6), Any(1,'ChuckNorris'),Any(1,2)]
>>> next((i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item.a is None), None)
3
```

Comment: Same idea as mine, but cleaner thanks to unpacking inside the generator.  +1

Answer (score 4):

```
try:
    answer = next((val for val in enumerate(l) if val[1].a is None))[0]
except StopIteration:
    # No element matching condition in sequence
    answer = None
```

This creates a generator object, so it effectively only expands the element you are currently inspecting, and once you find a matching target, short circuits out of the iteration.